# How to remove strings from a list which have same set of words (in jumbled order) as of other strings in the same list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have a list of strings in Python
For Example:

```
['abc xyz def','efg jk','apple','def abc xyz', 'orange', 'jk efg']
```

I want to remove duplicate strings from this list which have common words. The output of the above should be:

```
['abc xyz def','efg jk','apple','orange']
```

I have found `collections.Counter(a) == collections.Counter(b)` which can detect such `duplicacy`, but how to do the above task efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution is offered by the [`toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) library. Note `toolz.unique` is equivalent to the `unique_everseen` recipe found in the `itertools` docs:

```
from toolz import compose, unique

L = ['abc xyz def','efg jk','apple','def abc xyz', 'orange', 'jk efg']

res = list(unique(L, key=compose(frozenset, str.split)))

# ['abc xyz def', 'efg jk', 'apple', 'orange']
```

Function composition isn't offered natively, but can be replaced by `lambda x: frozenset(x.split())`. `frozenset` or a sorted collection is required since `unique` requires a hashable key. A sorted collection should be used if the *count* of a word must also be the same.

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
 list( {' '.join(sorted(i.split())):i for i in l}.keys())
 ['abc def xyz', 'efg jk', 'apple', 'orange']
```

or

```
a = [' '.join(sorted(i.split())) for i in l]

list(dict(zip(a,a)))
 ['abc def xyz', 'efg jk', 'apple', 'orange']
```

or

```
sorted(set(a), key=lambda x: a.index(x))
 ['abc def xyz', 'efg jk', 'apple', 'orange']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
l = ['abc xyz def','efg jk','apple','def abc xyz', 'orange', 'jk efg']
c = tuple((i, " ".join(sorted(i.split()))) for i in l)
#(('abc xyz def', 'abc def xyz'), ('efg jk', 'efg jk'), ('apple', 'apple'), ('def abc xyz', 'abc def xyz'), ('orange', 'orange'), ('jk efg', 'efg jk'))


res = []
check_val = []
for k, v in c:
    if v not in check_val:
        res.append(k)
        check_val.append(v)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['abc xyz def', 'efg jk', 'apple', 'orange']
```